# ValidationError for trying to use langchain with ChatOpenAI()

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I am newbie to LLM and I have been trying to implement recent deep learning tutorial in my notebook. I have set an `openai.api_key="sk-xxxxxxxx"`. This key works perfectly when prompting and getting output from GPT, but the problem arises when I import `langchain` and pass `ChatOpenAI()` then it tells me to pass `openai.api_key` as a named parameter or set the environment variable.

I have tried setting an API key in the edit environment and restarted the machine, still getting error. I have changed the `openai.api_key="sk-xxxxxx"` to `openai.api_key=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")`. doesn't even get to the `langchain` stage before it raises an error. I have tried so many steps but still doesn't work. I need help!

```py
import os
import openai

from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # read local .env file
openai.api_key = os.environ['sk-xxx']
```

and this is the error message to it

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\os.py:680, in _Environ.__getitem__(self, key)
    677     value = self._data[self.encodekey(key)]
    678 except KeyError:
    679     # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 680     raise KeyError(key) from None
    681 return self.decodevalue(value)

KeyError: 'sk-xxx'
```

Comment: Did you actually set the environment variable `OPENAI_API_KEY`? Do you know what environment variables are and how to set them? Look it up if not. Also please share a [mre] of your code.

Comment: Your [mre] has to go in your posts, never in comments. Comments here aren't meant for multi-line code at all. The formatting is completely destroyed, and for Python, control flow becomes ambiguous, since whitespace is used to distinguish scope, but comments strip out the whitespace.

Comment: @RandomDavis what I don't get is that, when I run the command '''echo %OPENAI_API_KEY%''' in my command prompt, I get a value returned. But when I try to print the value in my notebook editor ( either jupyter or google collab), I get ***None*** returned.
when I go to my edit environment variables, I see both my variable and actual value there.

Comment: Well obviously since Google Colab runs on a remote server, the environment variables from your system are not accessible by default. To use your environment variables on Google Colab, you'll need to set the variable within the Colab notebook. As for Jupyter, is there a special way you're supposed to set up environment variables for it? It might not just work right off the bat, you might have to pass them in or something, IDK. You'll have to research.

Comment: I have done extensive research even with chatgpt. when pass the API key as: 
openai_api_key='sk-xxxx' instead of api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY), I get no errors with chat_completion, but the moment I import langchain and pass ChatOpenAI(), then error raises:
ValidationError: 1 validation error for ChatOpenAI
__root__

Answer (score 0):

I did not use environment variable. Instead I used a local variable. Using the below code snippet worked for me.

```
OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-xxxxx"
openai.api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["question","context"],
    template="{question} from {context}",
)
chain=LLMChain(llm=ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=openai.api_key,temperature=0),prompt=prompt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a paid account.  Sometimes I  get the rate limit error and some times I do not.  Openai is having difficulty scaling their operation.  And openai is really expensive.    Unless you just have to use openai models apis for a specific reason, then huggingface, etc. has a number of models that you can connect to and the are free or just download a model.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried passing my [sk-xxx] `openai_api_key` as a named parameter and it worked.

```
chat = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model=llm_model,openai_api_key="YOUR_API_KEY*[sk-xxx]*")
```